# Merging regex rules into one?

Tags: regex, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

How could I merge these into one line? I'm sure it's possible.

```
RewriteRule ^forums$                   pages/forum.php [L]
RewriteRule ^forums/([A-z]+)$          pages/forum.php?category=$1 [L]
RewriteRule ^forums/([A-z]+)/([A-z]+)$ pages/forum.php?category=$1&sort=$2 [L]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
RewriteRule ^forums(/([A-z]+)(/([A-z]+))?)?$ pages/forum.php?category=$2&sort=$4 [L]
```

Note that you're still supplying `category` and `sort` to the PHP script, but they'll be empty.

I think you may have a problem with `[A-z]` including unexpected characters.  (Review your ASCII charset for details).  Replace it with `[A-Za-z]` or `[[:alpha:]]` if that's what you really want.